# Cython: function call throws error " function needs keyword-only argument"

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to translate my function from Python to Cython to increase its speed significantly. If I call it, however, it throws this error:

```
hhModel([56,-70,-55,120,36,0.3], Iext, 0.01, -30)       # stim is a 1x200.000 nd.array of the form [0, 0, ..., 1, 1, ..., 0, 0]

TypeError: hhModel() needs keyword-only argument Iext
```

It probably has something to do with the variable type of Iext. I tried to give it a list or an integer instead, same error message. I'm very new to python and cython, I cannot interpret the error message meaningfully. I will show you my function call as well as my hhModel below (in the screenshot: type(stim) needs to be type(iext), sorry for that).

[image]

**Create variable "Iext"**

```
# create stimulus vector
def create_stimulus_vector(nA, stimulus_length, zero_length, dt, plotflag):
    "create_stimulus_vector(2.5[nA], 1000[ms], 500[ms], 0.01[step/ms])"
    start           = int(zero_length*1/dt)                      #  5.000
    length          = int(stimulus_length*1/dt+2*start)          # 20.000
    stop            = length-start                               # 15.000  
    stimulus_vector = np.zeros(length)                           # array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])
    stimulus_vector[start:stop] = nA                             # array([ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.])
    if plotflag:
        plt.plot(np.linspace(0, length*dt/1000, length), stimulus_vector)
        plt.title("One Stimulus Vector")
        plt.ylabel("[nA]")
        plt.xlabel("[s]")
    return stimulus_vector

Iext = create_stimulus_vector(2.5, 1000, 500, 0.01, 1);
```

**Cython function .pyx**

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np

def hhModel(params, Iext, float dt, int Vref):

    ## Unwrap params argument: these variables are going to be optimized
    cdef float ENa = params[0]
    cdef float EK  = params[1]
    cdef float EL  = params[2]
    cdef float GNa = params[3]
    cdef float GK  = params[4]
    cdef float GL  = params[5]

    ## Input paramters
    # I    : a list containing external current steps, your stimulus vector [nA]
    # dt   : a crazy time parameter [ms]
    # Vref : reference potential [mV]

    def alphaM(float v, float vr):       return 0.1 * (v-vr-25) / ( 1 - exp(-(v-vr-25)/10) )
    def betaM(float v, float vr):        return 4 * exp(-(v-vr)/18)
    def alphaH(float v, float vr):       return 0.07 * exp(-(v-vr)/20)
    def betaH(float v, float vr):        return 1 / ( 1 + exp( -(v-vr-30)/10 ) )
    def alphaN(float v, float vr):       return 0.01 * (v-vr-10) / ( 1 - exp(-(v-vr-10)/10) )
    def betaN(float v, float vr):        return 0.125 * exp(-(v-vr)/80)

    ## steady-state values and time constants of m,h,n

    def m_infty(float v, float vr):      return alphaM(v,vr) / ( alphaM(v,vr) + betaM(v,vr) )
    def h_infty(float v, float vr):      return alphaH(v,vr) / ( alphaH(v,vr) + betaH(v,vr) )
    def n_infty(float v, float vr):      return alphaN(v,vr) / ( alphaN(v,vr) + betaN(v,vr) )

    ## parameters
    cdef float Cm, gK, gL, INa, IK, IL, dv_dt, dm_dt, dh_dt, dn_dt, aM, bM, aH, bH, aN, bN
    cdef float Smemb = 4000    # [um^2] surface area of the membrane
    cdef float Cmemb = 1       # [uF/cm^2] membrane capacitance density
    Cm = Cmemb * Smemb * 1e-8  # [uF] membrane capacitance

    gNa = GNa * Smemb * 1e-8   # Na conductance [mS]
    gK  = GK  * Smemb * 1e-8   # K conductance [mS]
    gL  = GL  * Smemb * 1e-8   # leak conductance [mS]

    # numSamples = int(T/dt);
    # DEF numSamples = len(Iext);
    DEF numSamples = 200000

    # initial values
    cdef float v[numSamples]
    cdef float m[numSamples]
    cdef float h[numSamples]
    cdef float n[numSamples]

    v[0]  = Vref                    # initial membrane potential
    m[0]  = m_infty(v[0], Vref)     # initial m
    h[0]  = h_infty(v[0], Vref)     # initial h
    n[0]  = n_infty(v[0], Vref)     # initial n

    ## calculate membrane response step-by-step
    for j in range(0, numSamples-1):

        DEF stim = Iext[j]

        # ionic currents: g[mS] * V[mV] = I[uA]
        INa = gNa * m[j]*m[j]*m[j] * h[j] * (ENa-v[j])
        IK = gK * n[j]*n[j]*n[j]*n[j] * (EK-v[j])
        IL = gL * (EL-v[j])

        # derivatives
        # I[uA] / C[uF] * dt[ms] = dv[mV]
        dv_dt = ( INa + IK + IL + stim*1e-3) / Cm;

        aM = 0.1 * (v[j]-Vref-25) / ( 1 - exp(-(v[j]-Vref-25)/10))
        bM = 4 * exp(-(v[j]-Vref)/18)
        aH = 0.07 * exp(-(v[j]-Vref)/20)
        bH = 1 / ( 1 + exp( -(v[j]-Vref-30)/10 ) )
        aN = 0.01 * (v[j]-Vref-10) / ( 1 - exp(-(v[j]-Vref-10)/10) )
        bN = 0.125 * exp(-(v[j]-Vref)/80)

        dm_dt = (1-m[j])* aM - m[j]*bM
        dh_dt = (1-h[j])* aH - h[j]*bH
        dn_dt = (1-n[j])* aN - n[j]*bN

        # calculate next step
        v[j+1] = (v[j] + dv_dt * dt)
        m[j+1] = (m[j] + dm_dt * dt)
        h[j+1] = (h[j] + dh_dt * dt)
        n[j+1] = (n[j] + dn_dt * dt)

    return v
```

EDIT:

The error persists after restarting the kernel. I use Python 3.6.2 and IPython 6.1.0 in Jupyter Notebook (installed via Anaconda). I'm working on Windows 10.

**create .pyx file**

```
%run -i setup.py build_ext --inplace

# import cyton function to python
import pyximport; pyximport.install();
from hh_vers_vector import hhModel
```

**setup .py file**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("hh_vers_vector.pyx"),
)
```

EDIT II

After introducing `int[:] Iext` and `cdef float[:] v = np.zeros(numSamples)` I encounter a new error, namely:

```
Iext = create_stimulus_vector(2.5, 1000, 500, 0.01, 1);
hhModel([56,-70,-55,120,36,0], Iext, 0.01, -30)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ownCloud\Masterarbeit\python\setup.py in <module>()
----> 1 hhModel([56,-70,-55,120,36,0], Iext, 0.01, -30)

C:\ownCloud\Masterarbeit\python\hh_vers02.pyx in hh_vers02.hhModel()
      8 
      9 
---> 10 def hhModel(params, int[:] Iext, float dt, int Vref):
     11 
     12     ## Unwrap params argument: these variables are going to be optimized

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'double'
```

**important part of my code now**

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np

def hhModel(params, int[:] Iext, float dt, int Vref):
    cdef int numSamples = Iext.shape[0]
    cdef float[:] v = np.zeros(numSamples)
    cdef float[:] m = np.zeros(numSamples)
    cdef float[:] h = np.zeros(numSamples)
    cdef float[:] n = np.zeros(numSamples)
```

EDIT III

What worked for me in the end was changing `float` and `int[:]` to `double` and `double[:]` (thanks @Pierre de Buyl)

```
import numpy as np

def hhModel(params, double[:] Iext, float dt, int Vref):
    cdef int numSamples = Iext.shape[0]
    cdef double[:] v = np.zeros(numSamples)
    cdef double[:] m = np.zeros(numSamples)
    cdef double[:] h = np.zeros(numSamples)
    cdef double[:] n = np.zeros(numSamples)
```

When cythonizing my .pyx file, however, Python still throws a warning. As the function works nevertheless, I consider it as a bonus to understand what it means (would be useful though).

```
%run -i setup.py build_ext --inplace

[1/1] Cythonizing hh_vers02.pyx
warning: hh_vers02.pyx:71:23: Index should be typed for more efficient access
```

Comment: Please replace the images by copy-pasted text. Also, for better diagnosis as you use a notebook, please check if the error persists after a restart of the kernel. In addition, can you give the versions of Python and Cython?

Comment: Thank! I edited the post, I hope you have all the information you need. Otherwise I am happy to edit my post again.

Comment: You don't need to use "pyximport" with the setup file. You can remove this part already (while waiting for further info).

Comment: `DEF stim = Iext[j]` will hardcode the value of Iext, in opposition to using it as a variable. compile-time definitions are not that useful here.

Comment: So, without the compile-time definition of `Iext` I could make it work. If that works for you, I'll write this as an answer.

Comment: `DEF` gets translated to a C `#define` statement I think. It's hard to know what it will do in that context, but it's definitely complete the wrong thing!

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! Indeed, the code runs without `pyximport`. When deleting `DEF` in `DEF stim = Iext[j]` it indeed works. I must admitt that shutting down the whole script (not only restarting the kernel) changed the error message in a way that exactly this line threw an error. Took me only one day to figure that out haha. This problem is solved for now.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl feel free to write the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the compile-time definition of `Iext` I could build and run the code properly. The compile-time definition will depend on the value of Iext when the cython cell magic is called within the notebook and will not work at all outside of the notebook.

Other remarks:

1. The use of `import pyximport; pyximport.install();` is superfluous and actually harmful as it is another build system whereas you have a `setup.py` based build.
2. I suggest having a look at Cython's [documentation for working with NumPy](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html) and the more up to date page on [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html).
3. For flexibility and ease of debugging, I also suggest to remove the `DEF` for `numSamples`. You can obtain the shape of the arrays from `Iext.shape[0]` and "cdef" it:

   ```
   cdef int numSamples = Iext.shape[0]
   ```

EDIT: For point 3 to work, you must:

1. Declare the argument `Iext` as in

   ```
   def hhModel(params, int[:] Iext, float dt, int Vref):
   ```
2. Declare the local arrays as

   ```
   cdef float[:] v = np.zeros(numSamples)
   cdef float[:] m = np.zeros(numSamples)
   cdef float[:] h = np.zeros(numSamples)
   cdef float[:] n = np.zeros(numSamples)
   ```

So that they are "compiled" by Cython but the memory is allocated by NumPy.

Comment: Your answer helps a lot, thanks! I have one more issue with point 3) and I'm happy you're emphasizing it, too. If i change from `DEF numSamples` to `cdef int numSamples`, `cdef float v[numSamples]` will throw `Not allowed in a constant expression`. But even when using  `DEF numSamples`, both `len(Iext)` and `Iext.shape[0]` throw `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Do you know how to give `Iext` the appropriate type? It's an nd.array when giving it as an input to the function.

Comment: Having a look at your reference, it sounds like `np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] Iext` where `ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t` should do the job, but it doesn't.

Comment: I added the missing steps.

Comment: Cool! Could it be that `Iext` does not contain `int` values? I get `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'double'`. Changing `int[:] Iext` to `double[:] Iext` doesn't help either though.

Comment: I did used int for my test, it worked well. I generated Iext with the routine `create_stimulus_vector` that you provided above.

Comment: To be honest, it also worked the first time running it. After restarting my system it showed me this error. Can you try to restart your script? If it still works for you something on my system is probably not working correctly...I'll wait for your reply and if it's still running I will close this question here and open a new one with the new error.. ^^

Comment: Are you seeing the error for the same line? After changing the first error the "new one" is for the declarations "cdef float[:] n = np.zeros(numSamples)" because numpy will return doubles by default and I changed these four lines to use `cdef double[:]`

Comment: I edited my post to give you the whole error message. I introduced the variables as you explained in your answer. I'm not 100% what you mean by " I changed these four lines to use cdef double[:] "

Comment: The error in the last edit means that you must change `def hhModel(params, int[:] Iext, float dt, int Vref):` to `def hhModel(params, double[:] Iext, float dt, int Vref):`

Comment: Now, you should also change the four `cdef float[:]` to `cdef double[:]` for v, h, m and n.

Comment: wow, what a rocky road. Finally it works. I'm so grateful, thank you! Interesting though that he ask me for doubles while floats seem to be fine for you. One last thing. while `cythonizing my .pyx file` python throws the warning `Index should be typed for more efficient access`

Comment: Add `cdef int j` at the beginning of your function. When Cython knows that the loop index is an int, it can speed up the array access.